# HOWTO: Change values in IList<object> properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects (rList in query below).  Each object (v in query below) has 6 string objects inside of it.  I need to query each property and change the value to null if it equals a certain string.

Is there an easier way to do this than doing 6 different linq queries (IE: one of these for each of the 6 properties)?

```
foreach (var v in rList.Where(ppe => ppe.Property1 != null
                && (ppe.Property1.Equals(warning1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || ppe.Property1.Equals(warning2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || ppe.Property1.Equals(warning3, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
            {
                ppe.Property1 = null;
            }
```

Comment: v.property1 = null; you can do it in one query with complex where clause. You can create list of warnings and use contains

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri He needs to conditionally null out certain values, not unconditionally null out all of the values.

Comment: Is this just to make it easier (which is valid) or is it a problem to traverse `rList` six times because of its size?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you can do is put all of the warning in a collection and then use operations of that collection in your query:

```
var warnings = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    warning1,
    warning2,
    warning3,
};
foreach(var item in rList.Where(ppe => warnings.Contains(ppe.Property1)))
    item.Property1 = null;
```

Note that as long as the set does not contain null values (meaning warning1, warning2, and warning3 are not `null`) there is no need for the `Where` to have the null check.

Comment: I think to have the same effect you need to use the `Contains` with an `IEqualityComparer`. The `StringComparer` of the hashset is for comparing the items in the set itself.

Comment: @GertArnold There is no overload of `Contains` within `hashSet` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  it always uses the comparer specified in the constructor (or uses the default, if the constructor didn't specify one).  This of course to be expected; one could not find the value in a `HashSet` using a different comparer than the one that added the items to the set.

Comment: Ah yes, it's an instance method.

Comment: That will work.  I need to have 6 foreach's, but that's fine.